# xampp mysql magento file import

Tags: mysql, magento, xampp

I am trying to import my backup database but it show the following error.
I even chaged the `Max_file_size = 512 mb`.

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted  
(tried to allocate 496821797 bytes) in  
C:\xampp\phpmyadmin\libraries\zip_extension.lib.php on line 65
```

Please advice me for same.

Comment: why no do it through the `mysql` command. It's much faster, and, it won't give you those memory issues. Also, 512MB or ram is a lot, and shouldn't give you that problem when importing something, unless is really frikin huge. Might be that your machine it runs out of memory because of other processes you have running as well, and/or, low memory configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Change the memory limit by `ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');` in your `php.ini` file. This will give you unlimited memory.

If you don't use php.ini already in your root, change php.ini.sample to php.ini and add above line.

Comment: `ini_set` is for run time configuration and nothing needs to be changed in the php.ini, it needs to be added in the script where its failing to allocate memory.